# sequence of sets with $\limsup A_n = \mathbb N$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf, natural-numbers

Find a sequence of one-point-sets $A_n = \{\ell_n\}$ with $\ell_n\in\mathbb N$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, such that 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n=\mathbb N$$

I know the definition of the $\limsup$ of a sequence of sets,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$
I know the sequence has to contain each number of $\mathbb N$ infinitely often, but I'm not able to find a suiting sequence.

Comment: 0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,...

Comment: $\ell_n = n\bmod \lceil\sqrt n\rceil$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$

Comment: wow, that's really easy. I guess I thought way too complicated... thank you!